# Azure WebJob not firing from QueueTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

We have several webjobs deployed to the same resources on azure. All have Timertriggers and one queue trigger each. All jobs have separate queues. All appear configured identically ( except for the queue names) yet only some will pick up messages off the queue and others will not. AzureWebJobsStorage and StorageConnectionString are set identically for all.
The first one of below will work in it's project , the second will not. To make matters more frustrating all work debugging locally against the storage queues.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be awesome. This is been days and I can't explain it.

`public static async Task ExecuteTVPresetsWebJob([QueueTrigger("execute-tvpresets-process-media-images-web-job")] string message)`

public static async Task ExecuteTVPresetsWebJob([QueueTrigger("execute-tvpresets-populate-schedules-full-files-web-job")] string message)

Comment: have you tried changing it to listen to a different queue / recreate the queue?

Comment: Yes I did. It's very odd some work some do not. Seems to be the particular webjobs. The ones that work always do , the ones that don't never do.

Comment: And they always work when I debug them

Comment: WebJobs is not receiving much attention since Azure Functions release. You should consider moving to Azure Functions instead.

Comment: I know. It's not my decision. I inherited this project.

Comment: These are long running processes. I don't think Azure functions is suited for that.

Comment: I see from the logs that the queue trigger function isn't getting picked up. Still can't figure out why.